# Cloning laptop HDD with two OSes to a SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, elementaryos

I have a new SSD for my laptop. It's the same size as the current HDD in my laptop. What I would like to do is clone the HDD to the SSD. It sounds simple enough, but there's a twist.

I have two OSes in my laptop: Elementary OS and Windows 8. What I'll try to do is connect them to my desktop computer and use clonezilla to clone the data from the HDD to the SSD. Is this a good idea? What problems will I encounter? For instance, will I have to align the sectors on the Windows 8 partition? How about changing the UUIDs in the /etc/fstab file of eOS?

Wiping and reinstalling the whole thing is not an option because my laptop didn't come with a Windows 8 disk and having to set up all of those programs would take many hours.

Thank you for any insight you guys may have.

Edit: as per Moab's request, here's my specs.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3531 laptop, with an Intel N2830 Celeron processor, 8 gigs of RAM, two USB ports, an HDMI-out port, an SD card slot, and a 500 gig HDD.  This little gem has UEFI on its motherboard.  It does not have any kind of optical drive.

The laptop currently has Windows 8.1 installed on it, as well as Elementary OS, Freya 0.3 beta.

The SSD I'm using is a Crucial MX100, 512 gig drive.

Comment: ssds don't use advanced format, so sector alignment is not a concern, clone should work, no harm in trying.

Comment: Your laptop should have the ability to make a set of recovery discs or flash drive, post you make and model, we will see if we can find more info on doing this.

Comment: I've posted my specs.  Btw, are you sure about the sector part?  Does Windows 8 still use sectors?  Because I've read that using sectors when they're not necessary could really mess up the SSD.

Comment: [Info on making a Dell backup](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN114921#Issue2)

Comment: Yes i'm sure...

Comment: Okay, I'll try using that Dell backup application, and then try using Clonezilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clonezilla should work fine. I've had great success with it in the past.

Comment: Great success in general, or great success cloning multiple partitions with different OSs and different boot structures?

Comment: With multiple OSs on the drive.

Comment: I'm going to use Clonezilla.  Should I just go with the default settings for the application?  I'm just going to use its "drive to drive" settings.

Comment: That should work fine.